# How can I get a list of the column names in my table where the values for those columns are not NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is how I can get a list of the column names for the table

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%tkrt%' and t.name = 'timerate'
```

So I get a list as such:

```
table_name  colunm_name
timerate    tkrt01
timerate    tkrt02
...
timerate    tkrt50
```

Now in the actual table based on the tkinit and the tkeffdate I get this

```
select * from timerate where tkinit = '0005' and tkeffdate = 
(select MAX(tkeffdate) from timerate where tkinit = '0005')

tkinit    tkeffdate                tkrt01   tkrt02  ... tkrt22  ... tkrt50  
0005      2014-01-01 00:00:00.000   440.00  NULL    ... 400.00  ... NULL
```

so the return has some values for tkrt01, tkrt22... and some of the tkrt's are NULL

I was thinking if I use the first query to retun just a list of the colunm names (tkrt01...tkrt50) and if there is some way then to look through using another query using a variable from the loop that checks if each column and if it's null don't return it.
Basically I want a list of the column names that have values in them so my final result would be

```
column_name
tkrt01
tkrt22
```

As those are only the two columns that have values in them.

This isn't the case for everyone as I have two items to filter on being the tkinit and the tkeffdate

Each id (tkint) has a different max(tkeffdate).  I have looked at doing For XML Path and For Each look but can't figure out the best way to just list the colunm names from the sys.tables join sys.columns where in the specific table (t.name) those respective columns (based on the two filters) have data in them

Comment: I think this logic is best handled elsewhere.